# Common Buffer Overflow attacks

Tags: security, buffer-overflow, penetration-testing

I am learning computer security and I am trying to find a list of common buffer overflow attacks, but not having much luck. 
I am planning on using metasploit for pen-testing as well as backtrack 5, but I haven't started yet.
Even pointers to a good sight I would love. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

this document introduce and covers many forms of buffer overflow attacks:

http://insecure.org/stf/smashstack.html

Comment: Thanks! Just a question, is it possible to write a buffer overflow exploit in python? Everything is in C/C++ (I don't mind, I can do those)

Answer (score 0):

in general you can differentiate bufferoverflows on

- control-data attacks - control data attacks may overwrite saved
  registers or other data used to control the application flow

and

- non-control data attacks - so attacks that try to overwrite variables
  to get e.g. more credits in a casino game

if you have more a look on the details you can then go deeper and have a look in how the attacks are really working:

you can then differentiate as well on

- the location where the overwrite occurs
- where the target is located the in memory that gets overwritten
- and on which location the shellcode is placed

if you take all that into consideration you have a huge bunch of bufferoverflow types to analyse - i did that already and it was quite fun ;)